# Is Sun not the biggest source of energy to us?

Tags: energy, thermal-radiation, estimation, sun

Probably in my 5th or 6th grade, I learnt in my science classes that sun is the biggest source of energy to us.

However, I was watching [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/DxL2HoqLbyA?si=ttdaKd_WXCD0zUHG)  according to whom the energy of earth is constant. The energy we get from Sun is equal to the energy radiated. So, what is actually true, please explain?

Comment: The two statements you are writing about are not really in disagreement with each other. We are not getting any more energy from the Sun than we are losing (except the global warming part), and that makes the energy of the Earth roughly a constant, but we are receiving most of our energy from the Sun too. There is a concept of entropy that will explain more things later on, but this picture is fine as it is.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I know a little about entropy. If we are getting low entropy energy continuously from sun, and radiating away high entropy radiation , so earth's entropy should decrease.

Comment: Sorry. i meant increase

Comment: As an analogy, your day job is your biggest source of money. That has absolutely nothing to do with whether your monthly budget is balanced or not.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Oh thanks. I get it. Nice example.

Comment: Your original assertion, that low entropy comes in and high entropy goes out, then if entropy is conserved, then Earth's entropy should decrease, is correct. But we are generating entropy, and so Earth's entropy can stay somewhat constant while we radiate away high entropy energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intro:** One thing we assume, because so far it seems to be true, is that the energy of the universe is constant. In other words, no matter what you do you cannot eliminate energy, only convert energy that is in one form into another.

**Short Answer:**
So it is like food, all the food that goes in must come out, it may be in different forms (urine, feces, sweat,...), or you will have to store it (get fat). If you're not gaining weight, it's because all the food you consume is processed and eventually expelled from the body. The same with energy.

**Long Answer:**
Imagine a cold winter, and you feel like turning the heat on. The energy that enters the heater as electricity comes out as heat, heat is also energy. So if you count all the energy in all of these new forms it has been converted to, you will end up seeing that the energy is all there. All of it.

Okay then... so energy doesn't disappear, but happens if we get 100 units  of energy per second from the sun and only throw 30 units per second out into space? Since it does not go way, 70 units of energy per second will accumulate on Earth and in no time we have a ticking bomb amassing so much energy it would make our planet a living hell. And that does not seem to be happening.

This all indicates that energy net balance of the Earth is 0, what it gets from the sun, it is used by the earth and then thrown out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).